# Status 45 (Not currently available as device) Nvidia Graphics Card is no longer recognized after long usage pause.

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using a tower PC with following sepcs:

- Windows 7 Professional (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
- 3,60 gigahertz Intel Core i7-4790
- Board: H81M-P33 (MS-7817) 1.0
- and a 500 GB HDD
- a single Monitor
- Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller for network

There is also a Nvidia GeForce GTX 950 but it is not recognozied by Windows or the Driver Setup Software.

BUT the Fan of the GTX is running! How?

How can the fan still rotate without the GTX not being recognized?

I already did these things:

- I used this driver software from Nvidia with the above mentioned
  result: http://www.nvidia.de/download/driverResults.aspx/134079/de. => But the driver installer said that there is no compatible hardware.
- I did a check for changed Hardware and run the Troubleshooting-Feature on Windows. => But it hasn't shown it there so no fix here...

I did check other ressources but they said that I need to reinstall windows to be sure that it is the GTX for sure. But I dont want to reinstall windows and the whole stuff on my machine which is a huge stuff to setup...

If any information is missing please inform me and I will update it here.

EDIT: I used the tower PC on a daily basis for gaming and movie rendering and then I bought a laptop for programming and then literally forgot about my Tower. Now I could need it for some more movie renderings but the GTX is no longer recognized. But I haven't seen any error message on the first use after the No-Use-Pause.

Comment: What graphics units are shown under display adapters in device manager?

Comment: @DrZoo it has shown the Nvidia GeForce GTX 950 as a device but with status 45 (Not currently available as device)

Comment: I would shut the computer down, remove the card, place it back in, and double check that the 6 pin cables for the card are fully connected. If you have different 6 pin connector to plug into it, try that too.

Comment: @DrZoo I dont know why it does work now... Its always the same. Just did your stuff and removed the driver beforehand. Now reinstalling the driver without the warning in the installation process. Will keep you update on this.

Comment: @Snickbrack the reason it didnt work is it probably was not plugged in all the way.

Comment: Did you use a new 6 pin, or just unplug and reseat the same connections?

Comment: is your video cable plugged into the onboard GPU, or the Nvidia GPU?

Comment: @DrZoo I just unglugged and reseated the old pins.

Comment: @drudge the video cable was plugged into the Nvidia GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU seemed to not be fully powered, which caused `status 45 (Not currently available as device).`

Before removing the device, the drivers were removed, then unseating and reseating the GPU, and reconnecting the 6 pin power cable allowed the device to be recognized again.

Checking power connections is always a good first step, especially for computers that have been sitting for a while.